# NSOutlineView as source list turns black when not active. Also not updating its background when moving

Tags: cocoa, animation, nsoutlineview

Instead of a regular NSOutlineView, I added a source list NSOutlineView to a view controller that is part of a split view controller (in case that matters).

If the application is front and center, it sure looks nice. But when I tab to another application my source list outlineView turns black while a regular NSOutlineView is white and stays white.

Am I supposed to do something to/with the NSOutlineView that I dragged and dropped in interface builder?

Also, when I move my application around, the transparent background of the outlineView is not updated. When you move Xcode around, you can see the background changing.

Comment: Please provide more information on the view hierarchy. I assume it has to do something with the sourceList outlineView and the splitViewController. How is the splitViewItem set up?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: No, though I haven't looked into it since. It's a minor issue though an annoying one.

Comment: Is your split view part of another view like a `NSTabView` ? It's the case for my app and the macOS UI guidelines say: `A source list that provides selection functionality for the window, but not the app as a whole, uses an opaque background. Here, you can see the opaque background of the source list in Network preferences, in which users select a network service to configure.`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

The bug can be reproduced when the `NSSplitView` is a child of a `NSTabView`.
A SourceList or any `NSVisualEffectView` with `behindWindow` blending will appear black when in background.

The solution is to not do this, as it is against [Apple Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/OSXHIGuidelines/WindowSourceListDrawer.html):

> A source list that provides selection functionality for the window, but not the app as a whole, uses an opaque background. Here, you can see the opaque background of the source list in Network preferences, in which users select a network service to configure.